# How to work with databases in HTML5?

Tags: angularjs, html, google-chrome-extension, single-page-application, indexeddb

I have SPA applications made with angularjs, but a need to make an installer to allow users work OFFLINE with a secure local database. I try with IndexedDB and I convert my SPA in a Chrome extension, but I noticed that it can be erase easily with CCleaner or from the browser for accident or something like that (I don't know if I'm wrong). I need to keep the datas safe! Maybe export datas to a file in a folder in each session. If the user reinstall Chrome and my extension, I want everything can be normal, with all datas keep save.

I really want to do an app that can be easily install (for that reason I tried with Chrome extensions) and run it EVERYWHERE.

What ways do you recommend to achieve this? Maybe, What Database do you recommend? Thank you so much!!

Comment: web sql is excellent in chrome and very very hard to remove accidentally by the user. problem is someone though it would be funny to remove it from the html5 spec so we cant depend on it in the future.

Comment: @ZigMandel Thank you, that's the problem. I need a security future.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a service like [Parse](https://parse.com/) or [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) to store your data online rather than offline.

Comment: That's explicitly against the specifications in the question.

Comment: Thanks, but my client asked me offline. Online is not an option.

Comment: @Xan I don't there is any other possible answer if localStorage is out of the question.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to use other technology like Java or Qt? It means that the promise of HTML5 running everywhere only apply online? Isn't there a way to use LocalStorage, IndexedDB with a safer way? Maybe saving datas in a external file? Can't HTML5 do something like that?

Comment: @bluesky777 I was under the impression you were trying to build a Chrome extension. If you want to leverage "HTML5" for desktop applications then take a look at Electron by GitHub.

Comment: @Rish, until now I don't see how Electron manage data offline. More, if I learn and create an Electron app, my individual clients will have to install any server? nodejs  (I saw oi.js) or something like that?

Comment: @bluesky777 you have access to the file system in Electron. What type of data are you trying to store?

Comment: I need to make a program for churches in the mountains (or field, they don't have internet) for inventory and treasure. It means that I can use Sqlite and HTML5 with Electron? for example?

Comment: Yep exactly that would probably be one of the better options.

Comment: If it's like that, please answer with that option if there isn't other way to achieve this.